# I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 and forgot to copy one specific folder, can it be recovered?

Tags: data-recovery

I have dual booted along with Windows 10. I deleted the Ubuntu partition in the hard drive in which the folder was present and then I installed the new on in it. I really need to recover this folder. Can this be done?
The folder was saved by the name .stuff
Because of the dot the folder remained hidden and was not copied when I copied all the data into an external drive. Please help!

Comment: Testdisk may be able to recover those parts of your directory that was not yet overwritten ([see this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)) - if that fails you may have luck to recover the content of some files using PhotoRec.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to break it to you but if you have installed on the same partition your folders content is most likely gone for good. Your install has propably overwritten any traces of the files left.

Answer (score -1):

i think it can be recovered using wind*ws .. but its really hard and you need hard experiment, because its another filesystem . and if you can't find what you got, you should try with another PC with your hdd docking on this .

i ever try this, and its work.

NB : be sure your hdd is not formatted again after that installation. the more you format this hdd after data lost, small chance to get it again .

Comment: Windows will not even be able to find a undeleted partition created for Ubuntu... so how should it be able to recover?

Comment: But i success to do that .. so its a magic

Comment: It would be really really cool if you could share the steps you took for anybody including the OP and me to be able to do so too.

Comment: i want i could show you how to do that, but i forgot it, but i swear i ever did that .